# Custom URL on Career 2.0 404

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

My created page with link[image: my page url]

The 404 page after following my new url.
[image: 404 page]

Comment: Just curious, why did you create new account? This might have something to do with this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Your privacy settings define your account as Private, hence the custom URL is not accessible.

To change it back, click "my profile" and in there click the "privacy settings" line:

> [image]

Now click "make my profile public" and you're all set.

Comment: Is it something new? The link previously worked fine with my initial settings.

Comment: @PM77-1 maybe the privacy is new and default to private, not sure about it.

Comment: The privacy portion is set according to a form when you first accept an invitation, but as has been pointed out, it can also be changed on the right sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, check to see whether your privacy settings are correct such that your profile is public and not private. It's something that we allow you to change when you first accept your invitation, but it's possible to change on the right sidebar of your profile page in edit mode.