# When my Careers profile is private, don't let me choose a custom URL

Tags: feature-request, jobs

As we can [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239047/custom-url-on-career-2-0-404), when the profile is set to private, the custom URL results in a 404 error page.

While this makes sense, it would look better if the custom URL textbox would be disabled maybe with a message explaining you need to make the profile public for the custom URL to work.

In the current design, people are missing the fact the profile is private, and wonder why the custom URL "doesn't work".

Comment: What if I want to choose a custom profile URL in anticipation of the day when I'll be making it public?

Comment: @Shog9 still, it would be nice to have "while your profile is private, this URL is not accessible" or something along those lines. I just noticed the preview URL is not a link when the profile is private which is good, but still the fact people complain here means it's not perfect.

Comment: Not in support of this; please let me choose a custom URL regardless of whether my profile's private, just like it being private doesn't stop me changing anything else in my profile. A reminder it'll only work whilst my profile's public is fine.

Answer (score 8):

I think a great alternate idea is to just detect if the user is viewing their own (private) profile and, rather than displaying a non-informative 404 page, display a message to them that basically says their profile is in private mode and not visible to the public. Also include a quick link for them to get to their privacy settings.

This would let those people who do follow the link figure out why the link doesn't actually work, without adding a bunch of notices on their profile page or just plain disabling things.

Comment: Great idea, I blame the late hour for not thinking of this myself. :-)